# Call to undefined function auth()

Tags: jwt, lumen

```
Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\auth()
```

If I follow through the step by step instructions provided [jwt-auth](https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/lumen-installation/)

I have copy pasted this [AuthConstroller](https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/quick-start/#create-the-authcontroller)

```
$token = auth()->attempt($credentials);

Error Message: Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\auth()
```

- Framework version    5.7.7
- Package version  1.0.0-rc.2
- PHP version  7.2.9

My [AuthController](https://pastecode.xyz/view/53e41da4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's more like

```
Auth::attempt($credentials)
```